# Download and move file only if it does not exist on destination directory, otherwise do nothing

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to install an executable command (`terraform`) by downloading the zip file, then extract it to the `~/bin` directory using a `Makefile`.

I would like to do this only if the `terraform` file is not already there.

According to the GNU Make docs I think I should use an "order-only prerequisite" with a pipe `|` (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) although I don't completely understand that documentation.

I've written the following target rule with the purpose of running it as `make install-tf`, when the file `~/bin/terraform` being already there, then doing nothing and returning. However this does not work as expected and I keep seeing the body of that target rule being executed no matter the file is already there.

- What's wrong with the following target?
- How could I install `terraform` only if the command is not already there using a `Makefile`?

This is the target:

```
TERRAFORM_VERSION=0.11.11

install-tf: | ~/bin/terraform
    echo "Installing terraform version ${TERRAFORM_VERSION}"
    mkdir -p ~/tmp/
    wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TERRAFORM_VERSION}/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip -P ~/tmp/
    mkdir -p ~/bin/
    unzip ~/tmp/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip -d ~/bin/
    echo "Done installing terraform version ${TERRAFORM_VERSION}"
    PATH=~/bin/:$$PATH terraform --version
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's wrong with the following target?

The target is `install-tf`. `make install-tf` will always run the recipe to make this
target if no such file as `install-tf` exists. The recipe never creates
that file. Therefore the recipe will always be run.

You require a recipe to make the file `$(HOME)/bin/terraform` if and only if it
does not exist. To a first approximation, this will do it:

**Makefile (1)**

```
TERRAFORM_VERSION=0.11.11

$(HOME)/bin/terraform:
    echo "Installing terraform version ${TERRAFORM_VERSION}"
    mkdir -p $(HOME)/tmp/
    wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TERRAFORM_VERSION}/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip -P $(HOME)/tmp/
    mkdir -p $(HOME)/bin/
    unzip ~/tmp/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip -d $(HOME)/bin/
    echo "Done installing terraform version ${TERRAFORM_VERSION}"
    PATH=$(HOME)/bin/:$$PATH terraform --version
```

which runs first time like:

```
$ make
echo "Installing terraform version 0.11.11"
Installing terraform version 0.11.11
mkdir -p /home/imk/tmp/
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.11/terraform_0.11.11_linux_amd64.zip -P /home/imk/tmp/
--2019-01-29 11:09:11--  https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.11/terraform_0.11.11_linux_amd64.zip
Resolving releases.hashicorp.com (releases.hashicorp.com)... 151.101.17.183, 2a04:4e42:4::439
Connecting to releases.hashicorp.com (releases.hashicorp.com)|151.101.17.183|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 20971661 (20M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘/home/imk/tmp/terraform_0.11.11_linux_amd64.zip’

terraform_0.11.11_l 100%[===================>]  20.00M  8.86MB/s    in 2.3s

2019-01-29 11:09:14 (8.86 MB/s) - ‘/home/imk/tmp/terraform_0.11.11_linux_amd64.zip’ saved [20971661/20971661]

mkdir -p /home/imk/bin/
unzip ~/tmp/terraform_0.11.11_linux_amd64.zip -d /home/imk/bin/
Archive:  /home/imk/tmp/terraform_0.11.11_linux_amd64.zip
  inflating: /home/imk/bin/terraform
echo "Done installing terraform version 0.11.11"
Done installing terraform version 0.11.11
PATH=/home/imk/bin/:$PATH terraform --version
Terraform v0.11.11
```

and second time like:

```
$ make
make: '/home/imk/bin/terraform' is up to date.
```

And with a little improvement:

**Makefile (2)**

```
TERRAFORM_VERSION := 0.11.11

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(HOME)/bin/terraform

$(HOME)/bin/terraform: | $(HOME)/tmp/ $(HOME)/bin/
    echo "Installing terraform version ${TERRAFORM_VERSION}"
    wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TERRAFORM_VERSION}/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip -P $(HOME)/tmp/
    unzip ~/tmp/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip -d $(HOME)/bin/
    echo "Done installing terraform version ${TERRAFORM_VERSION}"
    PATH=$(HOME)/bin/:$$PATH terraform --version

$(HOME)/tmp/ $(HOME)/bin/:
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(HOME)/bin/terraform
```

which runs like:

```
$ make clean
rm -f /home/imk/bin/terraform

$ make
echo "Installing terraform version 0.11.11"
Installing terraform version 0.11.11
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.11/terraform_0.11.11_linux_amd64.zip -P /home/imk/tmp/
--2019-01-29 11:38:32--  https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.11/terraform_0.11.11_linux_amd64.zip
Resolving releases.hashicorp.com (releases.hashicorp.com)... 151.101.17.183, 2a04:4e42:4::439
Connecting to releases.hashicorp.com (releases.hashicorp.com)|151.101.17.183|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 20971661 (20M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘/home/imk/tmp/terraform_0.11.11_linux_amd64.zip.1’

terraform_0.11.11_l 100%[===================>]  20.00M  8.88MB/s    in 2.3s    

2019-01-29 11:38:34 (8.88 MB/s) - ‘/home/imk/tmp/terraform_0.11.11_linux_amd64.zip.1’ saved [20971661/20971661]

unzip ~/tmp/terraform_0.11.11_linux_amd64.zip -d /home/imk/bin/
Archive:  /home/imk/tmp/terraform_0.11.11_linux_amd64.zip
  inflating: /home/imk/bin/terraform  
echo "Done installing terraform version 0.11.11"
Done installing terraform version 0.11.11
PATH=/home/imk/bin/:$PATH terraform --version
Terraform v0.11.11

$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Note the use of order-only prerequisites in:

```
$(HOME)/bin/terraform: | $(HOME)/tmp/ $(HOME)/bin/
```

That says: Before considering whether the target `$(HOME)/bin/terraform` is out of date, make `$(HOME)/tmp/` and `$(HOME)/bin`.
Then consider whether `$(HOME)/bin/terraform` is out of date but do not count `$(HOME)/tmp/` or `$(HOME)/bin` as prerequisites.

See also [4.6 Phony Targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html)

Comment: Your last paragraph is not quite correct.  What that says is, before considering whether terraform is out of date, create the two directories.  Then consider whether terraform is out of date but don't use the two directories when making that determination.  In other words, the two directories are always created first, regardless of whether terraform is out of date or not.

Comment: @MadScientist So it is. Improved, I hope.

Comment: Thanks very much indeed, that is really helpful. What is that `$@` thing when checking if the directories are there or need to be created? Is there any keyword I could search for to get the context around that `$@`?

Comment: @TPPZ You're welcome. Re `$@` see [10.5.3 Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)